# Send post data in a DELETE request from Django-tastypie testing client

Tags: django, rest, django-testing, tastypie

I'm trying to test a REST request using tastypie ResourceTestCase and api_client,
but it has a different behaviour from using angular js, for example.

The data sent for a DELETE request comes in GET parameters of the request using the api_client, but when I use angular it comes from raw POST data, how can I change the behaviour of Tastypie to acts like I expect? that is sending the data in the raw post data?

The current code:

```
    response = self.api_client.delete(url,
                                   format='json',
                                   authentication=self.credentials,
                                   data=data)
```

Comment: I mean, the parameters is being sent as in query params, not in the body like in POST, but using angular it's sending in the body.
How can I change that in the tastypie test client?